# Ошибка компиляции при команде git push heroku master

Tags: maven, spring-boot, heroku

Ок это моя первая попытка задеплоить приложение на heroku. Я следовал [этому](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku) туториалу, у меня установлена Spring CLI и Heroku CLI, ошибка появляется при попытке задеплоить приложение с приблизительно таким стэк трейсом:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
>   [ERROR]/tmp/build_c2569e1c27c1c307e42528c66e67c016/src/main/java/com/example/configuration/SecurityConfig.java:[123,125]
>   illegal start of expression
>   [ERROR]/tmp/build_c2569e1c27c1c307e42528c66e67c016/src/main/java/com/example/configuration/SecurityConfig.java:[123,126]
>   ';' expected [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project demo: Compilation failure: Compilation
>   failure:
>   [ERROR]/tmp/build_c2569e1c27c1c307e42528c66e67c016/src/main/java/com/example/configuration/SecurityConfig.java:[123,125]
>   illegal start of expression
>   [ERROR]/tmp/build_c2569e1c27c1c307e42528c66e67c016/src/main/java/com/example/configuration/SecurityConfig.java:[123,126]
>   ';' expected

Приложение работает нормально на локальной машине. Вот мой pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>solid_fuel_inc</name>
    <description>Web site for distribution of solid fuel</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            //при сборке этот плагин копирует статические файлы в директорию static как того требует spring boot
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Файл на который ругаются SpringSecurityConfig.java.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String HMAC_ALGO = "HmacSHA256";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myUserDetailService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic();
        http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenToCookieFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
        http.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin/**").hasRole(Authorities.SUPER_ADMIN_VAL)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin").hasAnyRole(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN_VAL, Authorities.SUPER_ADMIN_VAL)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/admin").hasRole(Authorities.SUPER_ADMIN_VAL)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/admin").hasRole(Authorities.SUPER_ADMIN_VAL)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/admin").hasRole(Authorities.SUPER_ADMIN_VAL)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/order", "/client").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").hasRole(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN_VAL)
                .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/").hasRole(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN_VAL)
                .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/").hasRole(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN_VAL)
                .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/").hasRole(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN_VAL)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll();
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

Comment: добавьте файл `SecurityConfig.java` в вопрос

Comment: Добавил, правда на локальной машине никаких ошибок при компиляции нету.

Comment: А текущее состояние проекта закоммичено?

Comment: Да извиняюсь, нужно было проверить, я забыл сделать Pull request в master brunch.